# Bluetooth audio out of sync with Internal Speakers (OS X)

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have a new Bose Soundlink Wireless 2 Speaker that I've paired to to my iMac with Bluetooth. It works fine, but I'm having some difficulties getting things working the way I want.

My main issue is that I can't get the Bluetooth speaker to play at the same time as my internal speakers (they are set up as an Aggregate Device). The Bluetooth speaker is always 0.5 seconds or so behind the main speaker. The main purpose of this speaker is to play music in multiple rooms and in places where you stand you get the weird echo effect of the two speakers. It's not pleasant on the ears.

I've played with all possible configurations of the two "Drift Corrections" toggles with little success. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Also, as an auxiliary question, I only get 1 out of 2 channels playing on the aggregate device. My setup is quadraphonic with channels 1, 2, 3, 4 in each respective corner, and when I click on the speakers the noise comes out of the correct speaker (all 4). But when I'm playing music from Pandora, etc. it only comes out of the right speaker of both devices. Any tips?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It still seems not possible to delay the internal speakers to match the BT device output :(